# Multiple Text CSS Animations Won't start at a specified time

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm creating a landing page with css text animations.
I want to have a few lines of text appear one after the other.
 Each piece of text should render for 2 seconds and start after the previous line of text no longer renders.
The problem, I'm encountering is,
the text renders as opaque and then goes into the animation start time and duration.
I want the animation to on page load,
  not render (left or top: -300px,)
and render once the first animation has stopped.

I tried various properties like animation delay and duration and ease to no avail.

```css
.header-animate-wg {
  position           : relative;
  animation          : header-animate-wg 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes header-animate-wg {
  0%   { opacity: 0;   top: -300px;}
  50%  { opacity: 1;   top: 0;}
  75%  { opacity: 1;   top: 0;}
  90%  { opacity: 0.2; top: 0;}
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
.header-animate-im {
  position           : relative;
  animation          : header-animate-im;
  animation-duration : 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes header-animate-im {
  0%   { opacity: 0; left: -300px; }
  90%  { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }     
}
.header-animate-me {
  position           : relative;
  animation          : header-animate-me 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes header-animate-me {
  0%   { opacity: 0; left: -300px; }
  90%  { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<div class="header-animate-wg">
  <h1> What's good!</h1>
</div>

<div class="header-animate-im">
  <h1> I'm </h1>
</div>

<div class="header-animate-me">
  <h1> Name </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the animations to enter animations, and to leave animation. Now you can use `animation-delay` (the 4th param, after `forwards` or `both`) to schedule the animations:

```css
.header-animate-wg {
  position: relative;
  animation: header-animate-enter-top 1s forwards, 
             header-animate-leave-fade 1s forwards 3s;
}

.header-animate {
  position: relative;
}

.header-animate-im {
  animation: header-animate-enter-left 1s both 1s,
             header-animate-leave-fade 1s forwards 4s;
}

.header-animate-me {
  animation: header-animate-enter-left 1s both 2s,
             header-animate-leave-fade 1s forwards 5s;
}

@keyframes header-animate-enter-top {
  from { top: -100px; opacity: 0 }
  to { top: 0; opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes header-animate-enter-left {
  from { left: -100px; opacity: 0; }
  to { left: 0; opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes header-animate-leave-fade {
  from { opacity: 1; }
  to { opacity: 0; }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header-animate-wg">
  <h1> What's good!</h1>
</div>

<div class="header-animate header-animate-im">
  <h1> I'm </h1>
</div>

<div class="header-animate header-animate-me">
  <h1> Name </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: That's what I was trying to achieve. Thanks!

Comment: I was watching a lynda course on css animations that didn't cover certain property/values in your code snippet like "leave-fade". What course or online tutorial did you use to learn css animations?

Comment: The "leave-fade" is just a convenience name. I've learned animations a long time ago. Some from [css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/?s=css+animations&orderby=relevance&post_type=post%2Cpage%2Cguide), and other courses, but mostly from play around with animations, checking how interesting animations on the web work, etc...